# How do I use spl-token through cdn.jsdelivr.net?

Tags: solana-program, web3.js, spl-token, javascript

I am having some troubles using the spl-token library. How do I use it?

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@solana/spl-token@0.3.9/lib/cjs/index.min.js"></script>
```

It is included it like that!

How do I use it now? For Solana web3, I simply use solanaWeb3.function(), but it doesn’t work for spl.

I also tried with this in my JavaScript file: `const { TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID, Token} = splToken;`, but then I get this error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: splToken is not defined

Answer (score 5):

`@solana/spl-token` does not export a global like `@solana/web3.js` does. It's an ES/CommonJS module intended to be bundled with your app.

Nominally, you could use an ES Module import like this:

```
<script type="module">
  import splToken from 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@solana/spl-token@0.3.9/+esm';
  console.log(splToken);
</script>
```

…but even then you will have other trouble – namely that `uuid` has [broken exports](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60830926/802047).